# How to map bool to a enum using automapper properly?

Tags: c#, enums, boolean, automapper

Could someone show an example with mapping `bool` property to a `enum` type? I'm worry about `null` members in destenition.
I need to have something like these:

`null` property value to a first enum value;

`0` to a second;

`1` to the last;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortutely, as expressed here [AutoMapper null source value and custom type converter, fails to map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378138/automapper-null-source-value-and-custom-type-converter-fails-to-map) you can't directly map "null" to something, because a map of null will always return default(T), so you can't do something like this:

```
    CreateMap<bool?, MyStrangeEnum>()
        .ConvertUsing(boolValue => boolValue == null
            ? MyStrangeEnum.NullValue
            : boolValue.Value ? MyStrangeEnum.True : MyStrangeEnum.False);
```

If you map an object property, on the other hand, it will work:

```
public class MapperConfig : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TestValue,
                e => e.MapFrom(source =>
                    source.TestValue == null
                        ? MyStrangeEnum.NullValue
                        : source.TestValue.Value ? MyStrangeEnum.True : MyStrangeEnum.False));
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        TestValue = true;
    }
    public bool? TestValue { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public MyStrangeEnum TestValue { get; set; }
}

public enum MyStrangeEnum
{
    NullValue = -1,
    False = 0,
    True = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like the below code :

Enum :

```
public enum BoolVal {
    NullVal = -1 ,
    FalseVal = 0 ,
    TrueVal = 1
}
```

Declare Value :

```
        var val  = BoolVal.NullVal; // OR (BoolVal.FalseVal ,BoolVal.TrueVal)
```

Test Value :

```
// This will return => null or true or false 
bool? value1 = (val == BoolVal.NullVal ? null : (bool?)Convert.ToBoolean(val));
```